# Requesting information regarding the use of MUI vs. the use of GetText for i18n/L10n of Windows desktop applications

Tags: c++, windows, internationalization, gettext

I have spent the past two days investigating which technology I will use to support **translations of text strings** (as part of an overall internationalization migration) **for an archaic (VC6) Windows desktop application** (with MFC) that is being migrated to Visual Studio 2013 at the same time that it is being internationalized.

**I have all but decided to use GetText to implement text (string) translations** (given the availability of [Poedit](http://poedit.net/), [Eazy Po](http://www.eazypo.ca/), and perhaps other tools; at least Poedit also includes a build of `xgettext` for Windows, and I suspect Eazy Po does as well).

However, the "Microsoft-recommended" approach to string translations is to use the [MUI tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317706(v=vs.85).aspx) ([muirct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319113%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).  I did research this carefully before all but deciding to go with GetText.

I will not go into the pros and cons that I identified for these two technologies, because that is not directly relevant to my question.  Suffice it to say that GetText seems clearly better, in my opinion.

There is only one area of comparison between these two technologies that I do not yet understand to my satisfaction.  Specifically, I have little sense of whether `gettext` (perhaps wrapped by [Boost.Locale](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/locale/doc/html/index.html)) is **at all standard practice** for translating Windows desktop applications in C++.

Specifically: If I were to learn that 99% of all Windows desktop applications written in C++ in the year 2014 (seemingly industry-wide) used the Microsoft-recommended "MUI"-based technology for string (text) translations, I would likely decide to engage in another day or two's worth of careful investigation just to be certain I didn't miss something.  But if even 5% or 10% (or more) used a `gettext`-based technology, I would be satisfied with that and I would move ahead and use `gettext` myself without feeling a need for any further investigation.

I have been unable to find any statistics regarding how common the use of `gettext` is for string translations for Windows desktop applications, in comparison with the Microsoft-recommended "MUI"-based approach.

(Related note: I did a search on my development machine for `*.mui` and `*.po` files, and I found only a handful of applications using either type of resource file; but the GetText-related `*.po` applications **are** more common, at least on my machine.  Interestingly, even some Microsoft applications use `*.po` files.)

I would appreciate a response from someone with experience in the area of internationalizing Windows desktop applications: Is the use of `gettext` (and derivative) approaches, vs. the MUI approach, for Windows desktop applications, thoroughly non-standard?  I'd just like to know if I'm really doing something out of the ordinary here - not that I won't go ahead and do it anyways :)

Comment: Possibly of interest: [Why is asking a question on “best practice” a bad thing?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142353/218240).  If your use case fits `gettext` the best, why should you care what others do?

Comment: @DanPichelman I thought long and hard about that before asking this question.  As a result of my careful consideration, I decided not to ask about "best practice".  Rather, for the sake of additional (relevant) information, I feel it is useful to know the statistics involved.  This would not determine my decision; for as noted, I have already all but decided.  But if the statistics show an *overwhelming* preference towards one technology, that is a factor that, in my opinion, would warrant a re-consideration of my decision.  In summary: My question is about statistics, not "best practice".

Comment: Can you explain how your question is not [spotting a herd in the distance and going trotting off after it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142354/102937)  See also [What's wrong with proving best practices through statistics?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6984)  I'm not unsympathetic to your position, but your question would be a better one if it asked *why* a particular technology seems to be favored.  That a technology is used more often than another (without a supporting justification) is completely uninteresting.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I do seem to be a recipient of a number of canonical metaphorical links explaining why I am asking a question about best practice!  I feel like posting a canonical link myself about the common practice of hunting down questions that can be fit into a mold, and then so doing.  The answer to your question is the same as my answer to Dan's.  I have already all but decided upon my approach.  The trends involved are my last consideration (after addressing many other considerations first).  In my case, I routinely buck trends when I see fit, and would likely do so here, as well.

Comment: But why would 99% instead of 90% matter?  It's the *why* that is compelling, not the numbers.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Just because it is not a good idea to follow trends for trend's sake, does not mean that trends should not be taken into consideration.  I threw out 99% to make a point.  If I were to say "99.999%", do you think that would make a difference?  What if I were to find out that every single application in the history of Windows was internationalized with MUI, and that I was the first person ever to do so with GetText?  That would be sufficient cause for concern, such that I would reconsider.  To me, that's not following a herd.  I suggest not placing all questions into molds.

Comment: I'm in the middle of writing a meta question about this.  Hold on.  The short answer to your question is "we're not a search engine."

Comment: @RobertHarvey Good thought.  I'll be happy to contribute.  Please note that while you're posting a meta question, I have just spent two days engaged in detailed, painstaking, and meticulous research leading up to my question because I have an internationalization project to implement, and it's darn near impossible to find useful information contrasting MUI against GetText.  But I've already done that work myself, and now I'm looking for a bit of input here on Programmers.  In the meantime, looking forward to your Meta question.

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7091

Comment: @Robertharvey If it were easy to use a search engine to answer my question, I wouldn't have posted my question.  I'm looking for someone who has some experience in this area, who knows of a legitimate source of information.

Comment: Of statistical numbers usage.  Snooze.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I snooze when I see nit-pickers hunt down questions in areas they presumably know nothing about in order to place those questions into molds, even in those cases (such as mine) where the molds don't fit.  Have you done any investigation into the issue of MUI vs. GetText yourself?  If not, you are not in a position to understand *context*, and context matters - especially for questions that appear to fit a mold.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I guess another way of saying the same thing is this: In my opinion, it's a better use of time to spend your time *answering* people's questions than it is to spend your time *nit-picking* over them.  If something unambiguously fits a mold, then flag it.  However, it's important to be willing to recognize valid use cases when they do arise.  In your case, I notice you haven't actually responded to my serious points.

Comment: off-site resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic per [help/on-topic]. See http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487

Comment: @gnat - I am not asking for a recommendation.  Where do you read that in my question?

Comment: "I would appreciate a reference to some statistics" => [shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) for off-site resources

Comment: @gnat - That's not asking for a recommendation.  It's asking for a reference to statistics.

Comment: did you check [meta guidance](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487) referred in prior comment? "Asking for a link to something or statistics..." etc

Comment: To be fair, the question does seem a bit off topic. However, I can see where @DanNissenbaum is coming from. If a given technology is only rarely used for the purpose and on the platform in question, it would make support for that particular technology a dicey proposition at best. It is also possible that there are reasons why it is so infrequently used which weren't discovered through aforementioned research. While I agree that this is off-topic, is there a better forum to which it could be migrated rather than the current back-and-forth disagreement over it's validity?

Comment: @gnat - I did look at the link you provided.  The link says `Questions asking us to recommend a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic`, which is why I pointed out that I am not asking for a recommendation.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum: We've tried to make that statement as inclusive as possible to mean "anything that would require us to link anywhere else on the Internet, unless it is in support of *an actual, written answer to the question.*"

Comment: To be perfectly honest, I think that I am experiencing a social phenomenon: the StackExchange population is large enough that due to the sheer number of members, there are a good number of 'scavengers' roaming the site seeking questions that they can pooh-pooh, even when they have no knowledge in the specific area of the question and no sincere interest in answering a question in that topic area even if they considered it valid.  Just my 2¢.  Of course, as a programmer trying to do hard work, it's valid to know if I'm the only one using a technology or not, even after heavy investigation.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That is a good point.  My request for a link appears in my title, and in my final sentence.  I have modified the title and last sentence to remove a request for a link.  I do not think this changes the overall intent or meaning of my question.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum The social phenomenon you are likely experiencing is the community consistently and routinely challenging content and content providers on the site for the purpose of improving the quality of content that is posted here. It clearly worked, your edit to your question turned it from a "shopping" question to a legitimate one. This is what sets us apart from the Reddit, Quora, Yahoo Answers of the internet. People will be better able to find quality content that interests them through a quick Google search.

Comment: @maple_shaft I've seen this phenomenon occur often - for example, users with a *high* number of points who, nonetheless, mistake poor grammar or punctuation in a question for a lack of research, and who appear to consider no more deeply than that, but who excel at the rhetoric of linking to the Help Center with a skilled elaboration of the flawed thinking behind the question. I do believe this is a social phenomenon.  In the case of this question, my edits did not alter the content in any significant way. I readily dispute your assessment that it was, previously, a 'shopping' question.

Answer (score 0):

From my scant research, both are similar, because they translate text that will appear in the app, but MUI handles MS Windows localised folder-names also (I'm guessing /My Documents/ etc but in French etc).

The 'Downloads' folder is called 'Overførsler' in Danish.

Being more mac/linux inclined I reckon gettext would be fine, depends who paying the bills for all this code :)